# Pytorch variable size input for GRUCell

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm new in PyTorch and I'm trying to train something with variable size inputs. And I want to use nn.GRUCell not nn.GRU. I firstly post padded the inputs, such that it could be of the same length. **I want to whether my `Model` class is correct or not.** What I'm doing is, I'm storing the output after every time_step into `output_sequence` and then only keeping the output only for the `trajectory_length` point.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, cell, length, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super(Model,self).__init__()
        self.cell = cell
        self.length = length
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers  = num_layers
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.rnn = cell(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size+1, self.hidden_size)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, self.output_size)


    def forward(self, state, batch_size, action_masks, trajectory_length):

        hidden_layer = torch.zeros(batch_size, self.hidden_size)
        state = torch.transpose(state, 0, 1).float()
        output_sequence = []
        for i in range(self.length):
            hidden_layer = self.rnn(state[i], hidden_layer)
            output_sequence.append(hidden_layer)

        output = torch.stack([output_sequence[l-1][i] for i, l in enumerate(trajectory_length)])    
    
        output = self.linear2(output)

        for i in range(batch_size):
            output[i][~action_masks[i]] = float('-inf')    
    
        return output
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know whether the `Model` class is correct or not.